# USB device blocked at startup by modem-manager

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb

When I connect my USB device to my computer it is blocked for about 30 seconds. When I run:

```
sudo lsof | grep /dev/ttyUSB0
```

I get the return:

```
modem-man  1125              root   26u      CHR              188,0      0t0    1116275 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

But this disappears after about 30 seconds and then I can use the /dev/ttyUSB0 with my other program.

I think the problem might be that I am using a VID and PID that is owned by another company because if I run "lsusb" I will see:

```
Bus 001 Device 035: ID 1234:5601 Brain Actuated Technologies
```

When I connected the my device to another computer the problem was gone and the the when I typed "lsusb" i got something like:

```
Bus 001 Device 035: ID 1234:5601 Unknown
```

Could I block this modem-man that controls my device for 30 seconds in the beginning?

I am quite new to linux so I am sorry if this is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you're not actually using a modem, you could just remove the modemmanager package. For ubuntu use:
`sudo apt-get remove modemmanager`
Then you have to restart network manager to take effect:

`sudo service network-manager restart`