# FT232 USB-Serial not usable with deamon

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, serial-port, serial

I am trying to use an USB-Serial converter with a program (a deamon) that is launched at startup on a embedded board (Odroid-XU). The deamon does not work since it fails to open the serial port /dev/ttyUSB0 reporting that the port is already in use (Device or resource busy).

Thus my first idea was that something uses the serial port shortly after the boot. BUT when I unplug and plug back the USB-Serial adapter, I have the same issue: I cannot use it for a few seconds. I checked with an oscilloscope the output of the TX port and it appears that it receives commands after being plugged or after the boot.

So what is happening here ? And what would be the solution to avoid that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem using `sudo lsof /dev/tty*` to find out what process was using the serial port. Then simply removing `modemmanager` from the boot sequence solved my problem.
BTW, I found the [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/568502/usb-device-blocked-at-startup-by-modem-manager) I needed a bit too late. I should spend more time on `superuser`.